# Update with nested subquery (sum) to get restricton on update clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-update

Got this bit of SQL as an update script, I've tried to add a work round to not being able to include the table to be updated as a clause in the statement so using sub queries, but  struggling to get this to work.

Essientially I need update a vailue in table 1 with the summation of a field in table 2, but only where the two other fields match across a couple of tables and based on field6 the restriction is applied to the update clause.

```
     UPDATE table1 W SET Field1=(SELECT field2 FROM
     (SELECT A.id, B.field3, SUM(A.field2) AS field2 
     FROM table2 A, table3 B, table4 P
     WHERE A.id=B.id AND P.field6=B.field6) B ) WHERE W.field6=B.field6
```

In the real world example, select the sum of points conceded in a rugby game when a rugby player has participated in the match. table 2 has the results (including the score) table 3 has the team sheets and table 1 and 4 are the same player table to be updated.

Hopefully this is clear enough and someone can point me in the right direction.

Tried the following:

```
     UPDATE $WSLKEEP W, $WSLFIX A, $WSLFIXPLAY B 
     SET W.F_CONCEDED=SUM(A.F_AGAINST) 
     WHERE A.F_ID=B.F_GAMEID 
     AND B.F_NAME=W.F_NAME"
```

but now stuck with:
         Invalid use of group function

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your subquery should be grouping on `field6` and exposing that column for inner join with `table1`. Here's how you do that [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE table1 W
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.field6, SUM(A.field2) AS field2 
    FROM table2 A, table3 B, table4 P
    WHERE A.id=B.id AND P.field6=B.field6
    GROUP BY B.field6
  ) B ON W.field6=B.field6
SET W.Field1 = B.Field2
```

And while we are at it, I would also recommend you to refrain from (ab)using comma joins in favour of explicit joins. The latter, however unusual at first after being long accustomed to a different syntax, can very soon become habitual and much more intuitive than the former. [A great deal](http://www.google.com/search?q=comma+join+vs+explicit+join) has been said on the topic, and some people may be holding quite strong opinions about comma joins. I say, comma joins can still have their share of use. However, when you are joining on a condition, the current ANSI syntax should be your choice.

Here's the above statement with the subquery transformed so as to use explicit joins:

```
UPDATE table1 W
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.field6, SUM(A.field2) AS field2 
    FROM table2 A
      INNER JOIN table3 B ON A.id = B.id
      INNER JOIN table4 P ON P.field6 = B.field6
    GROUP BY B.field6
  ) B ON W.field6 = B.field6
SET W.Field1 = B.Field2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually makes a lot of sense! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For an update query like you have above, you are allowed to include multiple tables in the `UPDATE` clause, even if you aren't updating all of them. This will make sub-queries unnecessary and speed the execution quite a bit. For example, you can do something like this.

```
UPDATE table1 W, table2 A, table3 B, table4 P 
SET W.Field1 = SUM(A.field2) ...
```

I'm unclear on the specifics of what you are trying to update exactly, but I just wanted to put out that you can often avoid sub-queries by using this kind of syntax.

Comment: ooh i did not know that, clearly!, i will give that a go and see if that will help.

Comment: updated post with current situation, unable to get query to work with group function error.